# Problems executing SQL-script using Firebird.NET 2.5 (Error Code = -104)

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Sorry for my English first of all. I have a problem and need help.
I have a simple tool made by myself on c#. This tool makes connect to local or remote firebird server (v.2.5). And my tool can create specified .fdb file (database) somewhere on the server.

Also I have a file with SQL statements (create table, triggers and so on). I want to execute this file after database was created. Executing this file will fill structure of user database - not data, only structure.

But then I try to execute my SQL script - firebird server returns a

> SQL error code = -104 Token unknown line xxx column xxx.

That's the line on this `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
(
    col1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(36)
); 

/* This next create statement causes an error */

CREATE TABLE tb2
(
    col1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(36)
);
```

If I will leave only one create statement in my file - all will be good... I don't know how I explained (it's clear or not)) - another words - why can't I execute full query with many create statements in one transaction? There is my main method which executes query:

```
public static string Do(string conString, string query)
{
            using (FbConnection conn = new FbConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = conString;
                    conn.Open();
                    FbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(query, conn, trans);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    return "Transaction Fail";
                }
            }
            return "Transaction Commited";
}
```

There is a query is my SQL file.

Answer (score 4):

As Victor already stated in his final comment, you can use the FBScript class for batch execution.

I was just confronted with the same task. This question pointed me in the right direction but i had to do some further digging.

I this example, the source of the statements is a external script file:

```cs
private void ExecuteScript(FbConnection myConnection, string scriptPath) {
    if (!File.Exists(scriptPath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Script not found", scriptPath);

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(scriptPath);
    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

    // use FbScript to parse all statements
    FbScript fbs = new FbScript(script);
    fbs.Parse();

    // execute all statements
    FbBatchExecution fbe = new FbBatchExecution(myConnection, fbs);
    fbe.Execute(true);
}
```

This will work fine, but you may wonder why this whole thing isn't surrounded by a transaction. Actually there is no support to "bind" FbBatchExecution to a transaction directly.

The first thing i tried was this (**will not work**)

```cs
private void ExecuteScript(FbConnection myConnection, string scriptPath) {
    using (FbTransaction myTransaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction()) {
        if (!File.Exists(scriptPath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Script not found", scriptPath);

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(scriptPath);
        string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

        // use FbScript to parse all statements
        FbScript fbs = new FbScript(script);
        fbs.Parse();

        // execute all statements
        FbBatchExecution fbe = new FbBatchExecution(myConnection, fbs);
        fbe.Execute(true);

        myTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

This will result in an exception stating: "Execute requires the Command object to have a Transaction object when the Connection object assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. The Transaction property of the Command has not been initialized."

This means nothing more than that the commands that are executed by FbBatchExecution are not assigned to our local transaction that is surrounding the code block. What helps here is that that FbBatchExecution provides
the event CommandExecuting where we can intercept every command and assign our local transaction like this:

```cs
private void ExecuteScript(FbConnection myConnection, string scriptPath) {
    using (FbTransaction myTransaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction()) {
        if (!File.Exists(scriptPath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Script not found", scriptPath);

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(scriptPath);
        string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

        // use FbScript to parse all statements
        FbScript fbs = new FbScript(script);
        fbs.Parse();

        // execute all statements
        FbBatchExecution fbe = new FbBatchExecution(myConnection, fbs);

        fbe.CommandExecuting += delegate(object sender, CommandExecutingEventArgs args) {
            args.SqlCommand.Transaction = myTransaction;
        };

        fbe.Execute(true);
        // myTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Note that i have uncommented the myTransaction.Commit() line. I was a little bit surprised by this behavior, but if you keep that line the transaction will throw an exception stating that it has already been committed. The bool parameter fbe.Execute(true) is named "autoCommit", but changing this to false seems to have no effect.

I would like some feedback if you see any potential issues with assigning the local transaction this way, or if it has any benefits at all or could as well be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Probably error in launching two create statements in one batch. Would it work if you break it to separate queries? Does it work in your SQL tool?

Comment: @Alex this is a common problem with most Databases they don't support more than one transaction in a query. MSSQL requires the use of the `GO` keyword to indicate that another transaction is taking place.

Comment: Yes, it's will be work, but i don't want to think about engine that takes one file, parsed it, and makes few queries - there is a many bugs i can allow.

Comment: @msarchet - Oh, it's a news for me. Thanks. But, maybe some tricks, some other ways...?

Comment: May be Firebird supports delimiter in a query. Or you could move this to stored procedure (some limitations are possible here too). Or run your batch with some tool like command line sql client or ANT/MAKE/etc.

Comment: Found solution - Firebird support script executing. FBScript class (NETProvider-2.5.2) provide it